# Emoticons Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, emoticons

How to open emoticons keyboard without setting up EditText to inputType="textShortMessage" ? I want to avoid that user have to in default keyboard click on emoticon icon to open emoticons keyboard, I want to open emoticon keyboard directly.